# changing/replacing root Object of cascades Application

Tags: blackberry-cascades

In my application i need to implement the "first run flow" , so in this case my QML scene will be diffrent. As last thing of this flow i need to run normal flow , so i have to change root Object content.
I don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

well
i have changed my class and added two function

```
   Q_INVOKABLE void firstRun();
    Q_INVOKABLE void normalRun();
```

Implementation:
firstrun:

```
qml->setContextProperty("dateModel" , ModelsFactory::getInstance().weightModel);
qml->setContextProperty("personModel" , ModelsFactory::getInstance().personModel);
qml->setContextProperty("Application", this);

AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();

app->setScene(root);
```

normalRun:

```
QmlDocument *qml;
        qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///main.qml").parent(this);
        qml->setContextProperty("Application", this);
        AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();
        Application::instance()->setScene(root);
```

as you can see i exposed **this** reference to qml 
and in qml , when the flow is finished ,  i can call Application.normalRun()
i can do this becouse i have used Q_INVOKEBALE MAKRO in function declaration;
Hope that it will help